# How to dynamically assign varchar variable size based on existing column size?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure in which there is a variable whose length should be equal to the length of a column in a table.
Is there any way that I can attain it dynamically so that I need not modify the Stored  Procedure whenever the length of column changes in the table.

Comment: How often do you change the length of the column in the table? For most schemas, that should be a rare event, if it ever occurs at all.

Comment: Yeah I do agree the schema doesn't change very often. But there are multiple Stored Procedures that refer to that column. Wanted to check if there is any way to assign the size based on the size of the table column.

Comment: *In theory*, user defined types (UDTs) should be the solution to this problem. E.g. you'd define a type that's based on a particular base type and then define specific length, precision, validation, etc, and then use that everywhere it's required. Unfortunately, the implementation of UDTs in SQL Server is so painfully broken that I've never seen anyone actually use them in anger. I.e. you can't actually change the type definition if it's used anywhere. You have to tear everything down and then rebuild if you want to change the definition.